# lightning:tile change the tooltip/hover text

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am using the `lightning:tile` component and want to show a different tooltip than the default - The default tooltip is the same as the label:

[image]

And I want it to be  different text, here is my code:

```
<lightning:tile label="This is my label" title="This is my tooltip">
    <aura:set attribute="media">
        <lightning:icon iconName="doctype:txt" size="xx-small"/>
    </aura:set>
</lightning:tile>
```

I was trying to change the `title` attribute of the component, but it does not work (maybe because I am changing the media - the `title` of the media changes, but the `title` of the label stays the same:

[image]

**Question**

Is there a way to change the title of the label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround but it's a bit ugly.

First, I remove the cursor action on the `h3` generated by the lightning component. The one which has the wrong `title` attribute.

Then, I add the link style to the container of this `h3`.

**Lightning Component**

```
<lightning:tile class="title-without-cursor" label="This is my label" title="This is my tooltip">
    <aura:set attribute="media">
        <lightning:icon iconName="doctype:txt" size="xx-small"/>
    </aura:set>
</lightning:tile>
```

**CSS**

```
.THIS .title-without-cursor{
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.THIS .title-without-cursor h3{
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: Indeed ugly, but works perfect, Thanks @MartinLezer